# How to figure out excel type from inputstream in POI 4.0+ version?

Tags: apache-poi

When I used poi3+ this function could be like this:

```
            PoijiExcelType excelType = null;
            if (POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(inputStream)) {
                excelType = PoijiExcelType.XLS;
            }
            if (POIXMLDocument.hasOOXMLHeader(inputStream)) {
                excelType = PoijiExcelType.XLSX;
            }
```

but when upgrade poi version up to 4.0.1,an error occured,Cannot resolve method 'hasOOXMLHeader(java.io.InputStream)',no such method,So how could I resolve this issue?

Comment: This has been removed. Do using [FileMagic](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/FileMagic.html) instead.

Comment: @Axel Richter thx a lot

Comment: You are welcome. But please consider using [WorkbookFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html). This is able creating [Workbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html) from all possible kinds of `Excel` data in `InputStream`s. So no need to determine the excel type. What file extension used to save determines on whether `Workbook` is `instanceof` `HSSFWorkbook` or is `instanceof` `XSSFWorkbook` then.